# PHP PDO Update - Expects Parameter & Invalid Parameter Number

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, error-handling, sql-update

So, me and a couple of friends are doing this project where one issue we need to solve is to be able to update data.

**DISCLAIMER:** We PDO connection works but is taken out in the code snippets for obvious reasons

The PHP code that's in use looks like this:

```
<?php
$pdo = new PDO();
$pdo->exec("set names utf8");
$pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING );

    $query= 'UPDATE HTSKund SET BranchU=:Branch, OrtU=:Ort, TypStalleU=:TypStalle, AdressU=:Adress, KontaktPersonU=:KontaktPerson, TelefonNummer1U = :TelefonNummer1, DatumAterkomstU=:DatumAterkomst, KommentarU=:Kommentar WHERE ForetagsNamnU=:ForetagsNamn;';

    $pdo = $pdo->prepare($query);
    $pdo->bindParam(':BranchU', $_POST['Branch'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $pdo->bindParam(':OrtU', $_POST['Ort'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $pdo->bindParam(':TypStalleU', $_POST['TypStalle'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $pdo->bindParam(':AdressU', $_POST['Adress'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $pdo->bindParam(':KontaktPersonU', $_POST['KontaktPerson'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $pdo->bindParam(':TelefonNummer1U', $_POST['TelefonNummer1'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $pdo->bindParam(':DatumAterkomstU', $_POST['DatumAterkomst'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $pdo->bindParam(':KommentarU', $_POST['Kommentar'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $pdo->bindParam(':ForetagsNamnU', $_POST['ForetagsNamn'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $pdo->execute(array($query));
    echo "Records were updated successfully."; ?>
```

**IF** we are using this method:

```
$pdo->execute(array($query));
```

We get this error code:

> Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in

**IF** We are using this instead:

```
$pdo->execute($query);
```

We get this error code:

> Warning: PDOStatement::execute() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in

We've been stuck on this for quite some while now and have no real clue of how to fix this so any help is highly appriciated.

*Note:* We are using a form to try and perform this, and the form looks as follows:

```
<form action="KundSidaU.php" method="post">
Företag: 
<select size='1' name='ForetagsNamnU'>
<?php 
$pdo = new PDO();
$pdo->exec("set names utf8");
$pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING );

foreach($pdo->query('SELECT DISTINCT ForetagsNamn FROM HTSKund') as $row)   
{
  echo '<option value="'.$row['ForetagsNamn'].'">';      
    echo $row['ForetagsNamn'];      
  echo '</option>';
}
?>
</select><br>

Branch:
<select size='1' name='BranchU'>
<?php 
$pdo = new PDO();
$pdo->exec("set names utf8");
$pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING );

foreach($pdo->query('SELECT DISTINCT Branch FROM HTSKund') as $row) 
{
  echo '<option value="'.$row['Branch'].'">';      
    echo $row['Branch'];
  echo '</option>';
}
?>
</select><br>

Ort: <input type="text" name="OrtU"/><br>
Typ av ställe: <input type="text" name="TypStalleU"/><br>
Adress: <input type="text" name="AdressU"/><br>
KontaktPerson: <input type="text" name="KontaktPersonU"/><br>
TelefonNummer: <input type="text" name="TelefonNummer1U"/><br>
Återkomstdatum: <input type="text" name="DatumAterkomstU"placeholder='YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM'/><br>
Kommentar: <input type="text" name="KommentarU"/><br>
```

Comment: You don't need to pass any parameter to execute() as you are already binding the parameter using bindParam(). Such call $pdo->execute();

Comment: Tried doing as you suggested but still got the error 

"Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined"

Comment: Make sure you are getting all values from $_POST. The error suggest you are missing some parameter.

Comment: change `$pdo->execute(array($query));` to `$pdo->execute();`

Comment: @Oskar.K u must learn to accept answers

Answer (score 0):

> Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter
>   number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in

You did not bind any of the placeholders you have supplied in your query

```
BranchU=:Branch
```

And in your bind you have

```
$pdo->bindParam(':BranchU', $_POST['Branch'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

Note that `:Branch` is not equal `:BranchU`  so you need to remove all the `U`s at the end of the `pindParam()`

so that you code should be :

```
<?php
        $pdo = new PDO();
        $pdo->exec("set names utf8");
        $pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING );

        $query= 'UPDATE HTSKund SET BranchU=:Branch, OrtU=:Ort, TypStalleU=:TypStalle, AdressU=:Adress, KontaktPersonU=:KontaktPerson, TelefonNummer1U = :TelefonNummer1, DatumAterkomstU=:DatumAterkomst, KommentarU=:Kommentar WHERE ForetagsNamnU=:ForetagsNamn;';

    $pdo = $pdo->prepare($query);
    $pdo->bindParam(':Branch', $_POST['Branch'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $pdo->bindParam(':Ort', $_POST['Ort'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $pdo->bindParam(':TypStalle', $_POST['TypStalle'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $pdo->bindParam(':Adress', $_POST['Adress'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $pdo->bindParam(':KontaktPerson', $_POST['KontaktPerson'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $pdo->bindParam(':TelefonNummer1', $_POST['TelefonNummer1'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $pdo->bindParam(':DatumAterkomst', $_POST['DatumAterkomst'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $pdo->bindParam(':Kommentar', $_POST['Kommentar'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $pdo->bindParam(':ForetagsNamn', $_POST['ForetagsNamn'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $pdo->execute();
    echo "Records were updated successfully.";
    ?>
```

Comment: cool glad could help see [how to accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: @Oskar.K you need to appreciate an answer when it helped u by accepting and voting for it